# Firefox showing issue with video.duration in html5

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, media-player, html5-video

I am trying to build a custom video player.

```
<video  preload="metadata" id="videoPlayer" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;">

</video>
<script type="text/javascript">

     var v           = "";
     var myVideo     = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {

        v        = $("#videoPlayer");
        myVideo  = v.get(0);

        $(".playlist").click(function() {

                         v.attr("src","http://www.jplayer.org/video/webm/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.webm");
                    myVideo.play();
        });

        myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {

            // in chrome it is working fine and shows the duration 00-00-33
            // but in firox it is showing Infinity.
                console.log(myVideo.duration);

            });
    });
<script>
```

In chrome video is playing and shows the duration 33.02 . But in fireox it is showing Infinity. So I am not able to implement the seek-bar. I think I am missing something

Comment: You're not going to get a value for duration until after 1) you click the button and set `src` and 2) the 'loadedmetadata' event fires. Try this example. Works for me in Chrome and FF. http://jsbin.com/awuqon/1/edit

Comment: I tried your demo. But when I looked at console it still shows Infinity in mozilla.

Comment: @brianchirls Even after click event it is showing Infinity. ie video is playing with myVideo.duration = Infinity

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins/extensions that might be interfering with the web page? Like maybe DivX? Can you confirm that myVideo is actually a video element?

Answer (score 0):

The duration of the audio/video is NaN (not a number) and the timeline slider is disabled in Firefox / Firefox keeps loading, but does not play the audio/video.

Make sure that your server sets the **content-length** and **content-range** properties in his response-header.